# CodeIgniter's Scaffolding and Helper Functions Not Working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm following CodeIgniter's tutorial "Create a blog in 20 minutes" and I am having trouble getting the helper, anchor and Scaffolding functions to work.

I can't seem to create links on my HTML page using the helper and anchor functions.

I put

`$this->load->helper('url'); 
$this->load->helper('form');`

in the constructor under 
`parent::Controller();`

and

```
<p><?php echo anchor('blog/comments','Comments'); ?></p>
```

within the foreach loop as specified in the tutorial. But Im not getting the links to appear.

When I viewed the source as instructed in the video, this line was missing (but it was in in the video):

`<form method= "post" action = "http://www.example.com/CodeIgniter/index.php/blog/comment_insert">`

Secondly, I keep getting a 404 Page Not Found error whenever I try to access CodeIgniter's Scaffolding page in my browser, like so:

> localhost/codeignitor/index.php/blog/scaffolding/mysecretword

I can access

> localhost/codeignitor/index.php/blog

just fine. I followed CodeIgnitor's instructions in their "Create a blog in 20 minutes" by storing my database settings in the database.php file; and automatically connecting to the database by inserting "database" in the core array of the autoload.php; and I've added both

`parent::Controller();` and `$this->load->scaffolding('myTableName')` to blog's constructor. It still gives me this 404.

Any assistance will be appreciated. Thanks in advance?

Comment: Do you have scaffolding enabled?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Franz. If all that is required to enable it is to put $this->load->scaffolding('tableName'); in the controller file's constructor, well yes I did. But I googled it anyway and discovered that Scaffolding has been deprecated from CI as of 1.6.0! 
 But I just watched the video on CI's site :( and wasted time trying to figure out why scaffolding is not working. Am I missing something here?

Comment: As Zack mentioned, it should still work. Look at the `scaffolding_trigger` setting in your config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scaffolding is deprecated, but it hasn't been removed until 2.0, and still works in 1.7.2.

You have `/scaffolding/` in the URL which isn't necessary, you just use your scaffolding trigger.

I'm not sure why your helpers aren't working, your syntax looks good, unless you don't have any data in your `foreach` loop. the `<form...>` line comes from calling `<?php echo form_open('form_controller_or_whatever'); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

```
localhost/codeignitor/index.php/blog/mysecretword
```

is just enough ....
check out this site:http://www.schobbing.de/user_guide/general/scaffolding.html you'll get a clear understanding ....